# How to check if a Json Doc has all required Keys in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I found multiple examples on how to check a json file if a key exist's but i am trying to do this a bit more efficient.

I have an import process where user uploads a csv file and then i convert it to json.

As there is multiple formats in my case for the csv file i want to check if a certain set of fields / keys are present before i import since most of them have different key names.

So to start i go and count the Key count in the json which narrows down my possible definitions. then i would like to use an array of keys which like

```
["field1", "field2", "field3"]
```

and then check if all of them are in my json file. As there a simple way or will it require to loop thru array and check for each key ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pull out the keys from your JSON object, but you still need to loop through the list of "required" keys and check that they exist in the list of keys. Something like the following should do the trick:

```
const myObject = {}; // getObjectFromCSV();
const required = ["field1", "field2", "field3"];
const objKeys = Object.keys(myObject);
const hasRequiredKeys = required.every(key => objKeys.includes(key));
```

To get a list of the missing required fields, I'd do the following.
This code would replace the last line above (with the `every` with the following:

```
const missingRequired = required.reduce(
  (missing, key) => { 
    if (!objKeys.includes(key)) { 
      missing.push(key);
    } 
    return missing;
  }, []
);
const hasRequiredKeys = missingRequired.length === 0;
```

In the reducer function, `missing` is the accumulator set to `[]` initially, if it is empty, then there were no missing keys. Note that the condition is opposite compared to the `every` function, as we want to know when a key is missing, not if all of them are found.

Comment: That works like a charm and is much better then what i had. Not to be greedy, is there a way to get a list of the required fields missing ?

Comment: I'd probably reach for reduce instead of every in the check - I'll add a snippet to the above answer.